# sequelize - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to set a 1:1 relation between two tables. RefreshToken table will have two foreignKey releated to Users table, as in this image:
[image]

I used sequelize-auto to generate my sequelize models.

**Users model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Users', {
    idUsers: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    },
    mail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'Users'
  });
};
```

**RefreshToken model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('RefreshToken', {
    idRefreshToken: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'idUsers'
      }
    },
    userEmail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'mail'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'RefreshToken'
  });
};
```

When I run the application, I receive this error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: SequelizeDatabaseError:
>   ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN: Cannot add foreign key constraint

I tried to add explicit the relation, adding in Users table:

```
User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasOne(models.RefreshToken, {
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
    User.hasOne(models.RefreshToken, {
      foreignKey: 'userEmail'
    });
  };
```

and in RefreshToken:

```
RefreshToken.associate = (models) => {
    RefreshToken.belongsTo(models.Users, {
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
    RefreshToken.belongsTo(models.Users, {
      foreignKey: 'userEmail'
    });
  };
```

But I receive again the same error. If I remove the references in the RefreshToken table  I don't see any error, but when I check the database I don't see any foreign key relation constraint with email and id of the User

Comment: Try to use only `userid` as foreign key in RefreshToken table.

Comment: Or you should use Composite Foreign keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780163/composite-key-as-foreign-key-sql

Comment: Here is information that Composite foreign keys are not supported in sequelize.js: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is common type error mainly occurs because of

#### 1. When the primary key data type and the foreign key **data type** did not matched

```
return sequelize.define('RefreshToken', {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11), // The data type defined here and 
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'idUsers'
      }
    }, 


return sequelize.define('Users', {
    idUsers: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),  // This data type should be the same
    },
```

---

#### 2. When the referenced key is not a primary or unique key.

You can not have two primary keys, so other referenced keys should be defined unique. `unique:true`

```
 return sequelize.define('Users', {
    idUsers: {
      primaryKey: true  
    },
    mail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true   // You should change this to 'unique:true'. you cant hv two primary keys in one table. 
    }
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you!!

Comment: In my case, I don't know why, in my db my reference was bad, the reference was with another table that was not correct, I corrected the reference and solved my problem.

Comment: My case was nearly as same as @LudOsorio's. Instead of referencing "clients" i was referencing "client".

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues:

No table should contain two primary keys and userId shouldn't be in integer it should be a UUID.

I had a foreign key set to INT and it gave me error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: foreign key constraint
>   "constraint_name_here" cannot be implemented

**Try changing:**

```
userId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  references: {
    model: 'Users',
    key: 'idUsers'
  }
},
```

**To**

```
userId: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  allowNull: false,
  foreignKey: true,
  references: {
    model: 'Users',
    key: 'idUsers'
  }
},
```

Comment: I have a table with two primary keys. It's a join table, and the two columns are supposed to act as a joint key. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: Hey Tom, what you're saying is exactly right. Those two primary keys are indeed primary keys but not in relation to the join table. In the join table's point of view those two keys are foreign keys pointing to the primary keys in different tables.