# Foreign key to a composite primary key

Tags: database, oracle

I need to create a foregin to a composite primary key but it dosn't operate. I think the problem is when i reference the foregin key table

```
CREATE TABLE CLEPRIMAIRE
(
    aa INT,
    bb INT,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_AA_BB PRIMARY KEY (aa,bb)
);

CREATE TABLE CLEPETRANGERE
(
    ee INT,
    ff INT,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_EE PRIMARY KEY (ee),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FF FOREIGN KEY (ff) REFERENCES CLEPRIMAIRE(aa,bb)
);
```

I tried to code it put it dosn't work

```
Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-02256: le nombre de colonnes de référence doit correspondre au nombre de colonnes référencées
02256. 00000 -  "number of referencing columns must match referenced columns"
*Cause:    The number of columns in the foreign-key referencing list is not
           equal to the number of columns in the referenced list.
*Action:   Make sure that the referencing columns match the referenced
           columns.
```

Comment: You need two seperate columns to store a two part composite key
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780163/composite-key-as-foreign-key-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE CLEPETRANGERE
(
    ee INT,
    ff INT,
    gg INT,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_EE PRIMARY KEY (ee),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FF FOREIGN KEY (ff, gg) REFERENCES CLEPRIMAIRE(aa,bb)
);
```

Is it what you need?